# Access a service within a buildForm function

Tags: forms, symfony, types

Is there any way to access a Service in a FormType ?

I created a function in a Service that returns an array, and I wanted to use it to populate a "select".

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Just inject the service like you would with any other class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't understand or can't inject a service to form type, simply pass it to constructor then.

example (in controller):

```
$myService = $this->get('my_service');

$form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType($myService), ..., ...);
```

and MyFormType:

```
...

private $myService;

public function __construct(MyService $myService)
{
    $this->myService = $myService;
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your [form type as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service). You will then be able to inject some services as for any other service!

```
# src/Your/OwnBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

services:
    your_own.service_outputing_an_array:
        class: Your\OwnBundle\ServiceOutputingAnArray

    your_own.form.type.your_type:
        class: Your\OwnBundle\Form\Type\YourType
        arguments:
            - @your_own.service_outputing_an_array
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: your_type }
```

Then, the service you want will be injected as the first argument in the constructor of your form type.

Comment: That's what I really don't understand... How can I put the array ( the output of the function in the Service) I want on the app/config/config.yml file ? Something is not clear, but I am sorry I don't know what.

Comment: It's much clearer, thank you. However I have an error on the name of the service: `The type name specified for the service "reporting.form.type.myArray" does not match the actual name. Expected "choiceArray", given "commandeDatas" ` (`choiceArray` is the service_outputing_an_array, and `commandeDatas` is my Form Type). Any idea ?

Comment: I think this is because the name in the `alias:` of the service should be the same as the one returned by the method `getName` of the form type.

Comment: Alright. It is almost working. "Almost". My array is returning 526 values (strings). I don't know if it has something to do with the following error I have now : `FatalErrorException: Error: Maximum function nesting level of '250' reached, aborting! in /var/www/reporting/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/SymfonyFileLocator.php line 124 ` ?

Comment: Nice! You have a kind of PHP stackoverflow! This is because you certainly use a recursive method (a method calling itself, calling itself, ...). You should change the way this method works to correct that because there are too many recursions.

Comment: Mhh. That's weird because I can use it on a controller and it works perfectly.

Comment: Maybe you don't reach the 250 recursion limit when you do it in the constructor. You can change the parameter in your php ini to increase this limit but I wouldn't recommend it. If you add the method to your question I can help you to improve it. Another possibility is that you have an infinite loop in a path of your algorithm that you didn't test in your controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67598/discussion-between-hellw0rld-and-gnucki).